# Make 6 subnets with VPC The maximum number of addresses has been reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to make VPC and 6 subnet at the same time.

Two are public with network gateway, two are private with nat gateway, two are isolated.

I made this code, from my understanding, it makes internet gateway, and nat automatically.

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "TestVPC", {
  cidr: "10.0.0.0/20",
  subnetConfiguration: [
    {
      cidrMask: 28,
      name: "st-sim-public-1",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 28,
      name: "st-sim-public-2",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 28,
      name: "st-sim-isolated-1",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 26,
      name: "st-sim-isolated-2",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 26,
      name: "st-sim-private-1",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 26,
      name: "st-sim-private-2",
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
    },
  ],
});
```

this shows error

```
The maximum number of addresses has been reached. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AddressLimitExceeded; Request ID: 5f04285e-f35a-4747-afed-66374befa511; Proxy: null
```

Why address limit exceeded? I just try to make 6 subnets.

By manual I did like this in aws webUI.

How can I do the same thing with code?

```
public
10.0.0.0/28
10.0.0.16/28

private with nat
10.0.0.32/28
10.0.0.48/28

isolated
10.0.0.64/28
10.0.0.80/28
```

Comment: Maximum for a VPC is /16 why are you not using that? Why are you saving your VPC IP addresses? You can't use that range after you create VPC.

Comment: I see.... That's right.. I need to rethink the desing of VPC